# AutoLayout constraints to resize scroll view when content size is dynamically loaded

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiscrollview, autolayout

I have a storyboard scene with several views, including a Container View with its own view controller. The scene's main view wants to be able to scroll vertically over all of its content, but the sizes of everything (including the scroll view's content pane) need to be set by AutoLayout. I've been trying to follow explanations given by several other questions here & in the apple docs, but there seems to be a hitch specific to what i'm trying to do:

The container view is given a list of items, and each item appears in a square frame. these frames are tiled five across in each row, as many rows as necessary. The number of these items may change at any time, so the grid's final height is not known. However, the grid's height does depend on the width of the container, because there must always be five across.

Thus, a sensible constraint would be something like:

`container.height = (0.2 * numberOfRows) * containerWidth + 0.0`

According to documentation, i'm supposed to set up this constraint to coerce the `contentSize` of the scroll view to fit all the things that are scrolled over.

However, you'll notice that it is the `numberOfRows` component of this constraint that changes dynamically -- this is a part of the `multiplier` property of the constraint, when i save it with an IBOutlet. And when I tried to make the content-fetching callback change the multiplier, it gets compiler error because `multiplier` is read-only.

How can I change the height of this subview of the scroller dynamically, while still using autolayout?

This image hopefully shows something of what I'm trying to do. Everything above the last container view is correctly aligned with constraints. The last one should have a grid of squares (unknown count). The squares are correctly given their sizes by layout constraints I create programmatically. But at the moment, the scroll view's content size is being fixed to the size of the scroll view, rather than being expanded to include the tall collage -- so no scrolling happens! [image: Storyboard setup]

Answer (score 0):

The reason I found this problem was happening was that I wasn't correctly using "placeholder constraints". Basically, I had to set up all my constraints as if I wasn't going to change any frames in code. However, on the one constraint that would conflict with my programmatic frame changes -- the height of the bottom container -- I had to enable "placeholder (remove before build)" in the inspector pane. I suppose this allows the Interface Builder to assume the promise that the height dimension will be provided at runtime.

One caveat when doing this was that the now unconstrained height was unpredictable until I set it manually. So I had to go and set a default initial height in `viewDidLoad`.

From what I can tell, this will be the correct way to do something like this until something like "Loading-only constraints" are created -- constraints that affect initial load positions, but don't constrain when the frame is laid out again. No idea if this is coming or even possible, however.